# Remember text box value using jQuery cookies

Tags: jquery, html, cookies

I have a text box and submit button in my page. When I click on Submit button, the page refreshes. I want to remember the last entered value to the text box after refresh. How can I do that using jQuery? I have the following

```
  <input type="text" id = "textbox"> <br/>
  <input type="Submit" value = " Submit " onClick = " javascript:window.location.reload(); ">
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use `local storage` for the issue

```
localStorage.setItem('yourIndex',$('#textbox').val());
```

and now if you want to retrieve the item

```
localStorage.getItem('yourIndex');
```

`local storage` is supported by all latest browsers.

Answer (score 0):

to save cookie:

```
$.cookie(key,value,{ expires: expire }); //expire in days.
```

to get cookie :

```
$.cookie(key);
```

of course you need to js, which you can get from :

http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

```
function OnSubmit (){
    $.cookie("textbox",$("#textbox").val(),{ expires: 1}); //stores cookie for 1 day, names textbox and stores the value
    window.location.reload();
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var value = $.cookie("textbox");
    $("#textbox").val(value === undefined || value === null ? "" : value); //insert the value stored in cookie "textbox" only if its not null or undefined , if it does insert empty string
});
```

And ofcourse : `onClick:OnSubmit`