# Prevent input value from resetting on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, input

I've noticed that in Firefox an input element maintains its value when the page is reset but not in Safari. Is there a way to maintain the values a user would have typed in JavaScript (no PHP).

I've tried Googling this fairly extensively but every result seems to find this behavior undesirable.

**Edit:** Not sure what I am doing wrong, this is what I tried:

```
<input id="myInput" type="text">
<script>
    var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");

    if (sessionStorage.getItem("autosave"))
        myInput.value = sessionStorage.getItem("autosave");

    myInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
        sessionStorage.setItem("autosave", myInput.value);
    });
</script>
```

**Edit (again):** Got it working, thank you:

```
<input id="myInput" type="text">
<script>
    var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");

    window.onload = function() {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("autosave"))
            myInput.value = sessionStorage.getItem("autosave");
    }

    myInput.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
        sessionStorage.setItem("autosave", myInput.value);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You could save values to localstorage on input change, and clear on submit. Then, when loading the page, you check for localstorage values and populate the form.

Comment: This is browser feature , even in Firefox input elements will get reset if you do "hard-refresh" by clicking CTRL+F5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input id="persistent_text_field" value=""/>
```

In your `JS` assuming you're using `jQuery`

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('last_entry')){
        $("#persistent_text_field").val(sessionStorage.getItem('last_entry'));
    }

    $("#persistent_text_field").on("keypress",function(){
        sessionStorage.setItem('last_entry',$(this).val());
    });
});
```

EDIT:
Non jQuery Solution? Simple :)

```
<input id="persistent_text_field" value="" onkeypress="setStorage(this)"/>
```

In your `JavaScript` file call `customReset();` in your document load event handler function.

```
function customReset(){
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('last_entry')){
        var element = document.getElementById("presistent_text_field");
        element.value = sessionStorage.getItem('last_entry');
    }
}

function setStorage(element){
    sessionStorage.setItem('last_entry',element.value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I would prefer a non jQuery solution

Answer (score 5):

I think [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage) would be ideal for this since [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage) and cookies would persist the values across sessions which is probably not what you would want.

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about that option. :-) It seems to be supported by all modern browsers http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage

Comment: Yes, probably the best solution. (Cookies can be deleted / set to expire too by the way, but it requires to do more.)

Answer (score 0):

It is a browser behavior, but you can try to override it using cookies to remember entries, if you do not want to use PHP.

```
document.cookie = "field=value";
```

Comment: I am not sure how to make use of this, could you make an example? I updated my question to show some minimal HTML and JavaScript based on another answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to store value in cookie or in local storage.

[Remember text box value using jQuery cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257845/remember-text-box-value-using-jquery-cookies)

Comment: Thank you but I would prefer a non jQuery solution

Answer (score 0):

Firefox itself gives an answer to this, code and all in the link:

[Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

The example is given in Javascript